# How to switch Windows 10 product key?

Tags: windows-10, license, licensing

I have two versions of Windows 10 licensed to my Microsoft account: Windows 10 Pro in my old computer and Windows 10 Home in my laptop. I want to transfer the Pro license to my laptop, however I couldn't find how to do so anywhere.

Comment: This cannot be done.  The Windows 10 Home license cannot be used on another machine.  OEM licenses cannot be transferred.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I transfer Windows 10 Pro license to another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1119334/can-i-transfer-windows-10-pro-license-to-another-computer)

Comment: @Ramhound The Windows 10 Home license is a OEM, however my Pro license is from an update from a retail Windows 7 Ultimate Edition to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: If that is the case you can do an in-place upgrade to Professional from within Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Professional.  You can also modify the ISO you used and specify it's a retail ISO thus allowing you to input a license key at installation.

Comment: I'm having no luck with the in-place upgrade. I have followed the instructions from this question: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/how-to-perform-an-in-place-upgrade-with-windows-10/7f0b236e-3c6c-4913-9691-c4baa2a6190a, however it straight up selects the same version that's already installed. How can I do the latter? Could I, perhaps, use a bootable flash drive?

Comment: If you want help with the in-place upgrade you have to provide more detail information other than "I'm having no luck" because I can't answer a question with so little information.  The second duplicate is a workaround to doing a in-place upgrade

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: Possible solution to it not installing selected version.....https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: @Moab - "Jinx owe me a Coke!" ;-)

Comment: @Ramhound dang did not see your comment!